# How to get bibliography with DOI instead of URL in elsarticle?

Tags: bibliographies, elsarticle, doi

I'm using

```
\documentclass[final,3p,twocolumn,number, sort&compress]{elsarticle}

\bibliographystyle{elsarticle-harv}

\begin{document}

Text citing an article \cite{Andersen20132}.

\bibliography{references}

\end{document}
```

My bibtex-file *references.bib* contains this entry:

```
@Article{Andersen20132,
  Title                    = {Long term forecasting of hourly electricity consumption in local areas in Denmark },
  Author                   = {F.M. Andersen and H.V. Larsen and R.B. Gaardestrup},
  Journal                  = {Applied Energy },
  Year                     = {2013},
  Number                   = {0},
  Pages                    = {147 - 162},
  Volume                   = {110},
  Doi                      = {http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.apenergy.2013.04.046},
  ISSN                     = {0306-2619},
  Keywords                 = {Long term electricity consumption},
  Owner                    = {aki},
  Timestamp                = {2014.05.07},
  Url                      = {http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0306261913003413}
}
```

Elsevier recommends to use DOI in bibliography entries. However, URL is printed instead of DOI.

How can I change this?

Comment: BTW: Nobody has welcomed you here yet. So: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `elsarticle-harv.bst` style file does not provide any support for DOIs.

What you can do is to use the `url` field to set the DOI

```
Url                      = {http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.apenergy.2013.04.046}
```

and put this line in the preamble:

```
\def\urlprefix{DOI }
```

MWE

```
\begin{filecontents*}{references.bib}
@Article{Andersen20132,
  Title                    = {Long term forecasting of hourly electricity consumption in local areas in Denmark },
  Author                   = {F.M. Andersen and H.V. Larsen and R.B. Gaardestrup},
  Journal                  = {Applied Energy },
  Year                     = {2013},
  Number                   = {0},
  Pages                    = {147 - 162},
  Volume                   = {110},
  ISSN                     = {0306-2619},
  Keywords                 = {Long term electricity consumption},
  Owner                    = {aki},
  Timestamp                = {2014.05.07},
  Url                      = {http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.apenergy.2013.04.046}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass[final,3p,twocolumn,number, sort&compress]{elsarticle}

\usepackage{url} % just for breaking urls

\def\urlprefix{DOI }

\begin{document}

Text citing an article \cite{Andersen20132}.

\bibliographystyle{elsarticle-harv}
\raggedright
\bibliography{references}

\end{document}
```

Output

[image]

Comment: not sure the `http://dx.doi.org/` should be included in the DOI reference even though you use the url entry. Something like `\href{http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.apenergy.2013.04.046}{10.1016/j.apenergy.2013.04.046}` would be more appropriate, don't you think?

Comment: @pluton I don't know...

Comment: @karlkoeller: Thank you for this solution. I feel it is strange that Elsevier recommends to include DOI and at the same time a bibliography style that does not support it. I wonder how authors deal with this normally. Most references can be downloaded directly as bibtex entry. However, changing the URL of each entry manually can be time consuming...

Comment: @Aki You can switch from `elsarticle-harv` to `elsarticle-num` which has support for DOIs. It prints both the DOIs and the URLs.

Comment: @karlkoeller: Is there really no way to manually control for which details are printed in the bibliography? In case I don't want to print URLs but only DOIs, for example.

Comment: @Aki No, unless you want to rewrite part of the `.bst` style file.

Answer (score 4):

There is an updated version of the `elsarticle-harv.bst` which has support for printing the DOI.

http://support.river-valley.com/wiki/index.php?title=Model-wise_bibliographic_style_files

unfortunately they do not push this to CTAN :(